# "The me of the past"

Tags: grammar, phrases, phrase-requests

When talking about one's self in the past, is "the me of the past" grammatically correct?

I'm trying to make a sentence like this:

> The me of the past who was popular
>   with girls, I'm jealous of him.

Is there anything wrong with this sentence? Are there better ways to say this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Spoken, it is colloquially acceptable.  It's not really grammatically precise, but in informal speech, you can fudge the rules a little.

If your sentence is going to be in written form, you should say something more like this:

> I'm jealous of my past self, who was popular with girls.

If you want to be grammatically accurate, you will be hard-pressed to come up with a natural-sounding substitute for a construct involving theoretical separation between one's present self and one's past self.

Comment: "My past self" is definitely the more common way to say this. +1.

Comment: I would prefer "my former self" instead.

Comment: Just because there are more common ways to express the sentiment, doesn't mean OP's usage isn't valid. It's a little odd, which is why some writers quotate "**me**", but I don't really see any problem with the grammar as such. I think it's just that we feel a bit uncomfortable saying "the me" because it disturbs our semantic sensibilities. Anyway, people (including psychologists) do sometimes write it, so it is not just a feature of casual speech.

Answer (score 3):

Questions:

> Is there anything wrong with this sentence?

No, nothing really wrong with it

> Are there better ways to say this?

Yes, I would suggest using:

> My self of the past who was popular with the girls, I am jealous of him.
>   or
>   I am jealous of my past self, who was popular with the girls.

Comment: I am jealous of my past self that was popular with girls.

Answer (score 1):

"I'd love to go back and ask the 21 year old me, but he'd be too busy with the latest girlfriend to pay any attention. Sometimes I wish I was him."